# Python 3 and Dll with API in c# , importing dll files

Tags: python, c#

I need to call a method from an DLL with pythonnet. This methods expects a list of a specific type to fill in the returned objects.
the code is written C# and I want to implement it in python
when I run the code I am not able to import Hbm

```
import sys
import clr
import ctypes
#change the sys.path
sys.path.insert(1,"E:\API\")
clr.AddReference("Hbm.Api.Common")
clr.AddReference("System.Collections")
from System.Collections.Generic import List
from Hbm.Api.Common import DaqEnvironment
from Hbm.Api.Common.Entities import Device
from Hbm.Api.Common.Entities.Problems import CommunicationFailedError
from Hbm.Api.Common.Entities.Channels import Channel
from Hbm.Api.Common.Entities.Problems import Problem
from Hbm.Api.Common.Enums import SettingType
from Hbm.Api.Common.Enums import LedFlashMode
clr.AddReference("Hbm.Api.QuantumX")
from Hbm.Api.QuantumX import QuantumXDevice
from Hbm.Api.QuantumX import QuantumXDeviceFamily


inst = DaqEnvironment.GetInstance()  # there is no constructor for the environment
deviceList = inst.Scan()

#quantum = QuantumXDevice("10.10.10.100")
quantumFamily = QuantumXDeviceFamily()
retDevices = quantumFamily.Scan()
quantum = retDevices[0]

print('Yipiih: QuantumX Found: HW Number: ' + quantum.SerialNo)

#Problem = Problem()  # this is not possible as it is an abstract class
typeProb = clr.GetClrType(Problem)
dummyProb = typeProb()
connect_problems = List[Problem]()
is_ok = env.Connect(found_devices[0], connect_problems)
#call the Connect Method:
connected, retList = DaqEnvironment.Connect(retDevices[0], typeProb)
```

here is error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/ahmad/PycharmProjects/pyside6_project1/test2.py", line 11, in 
from Hbm.Api.Common import DaqEnvironment
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Hbm

the API is in C# fo data acquisition device , I want to use python because I use other instruments with python in the same project with the Pyside6graphical user interface.

Comment: sys.path.insert(1,"E:\API")  Is there a backslash missing here?

Comment: Actually I change the name of file after running the code, I change it , but not solve the Problem

Comment: Try this sys.path.insert(1,"E:\\API")

Comment: The Problem it finds the dll file but couldnot import the method, so this line is not the problem

Comment: @AhmadAttar did you ever solve for this? Or have an API ready for the hbm devices

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
sys.path.insert(1,"E:\API\")
```

try to delete the latest `\` and use:

```
sys.path.insert(1,"E:\API")
```